# Xamarin Forms - Duplicate Toolbar Appearing On Pages Issue

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

[image]
I'm building a shopping cart and I have a very annoying problem with a double toolbar being displayed on my pages.

I spent several hours on this and having issues trying to fix it.

My current pages are setup like so:

1. MainHomePage (This contains a menu and an embedded page titled "MainHomePageDetail")

[image]

2. MainHomePageDetail (this contains a list of images where the user will click on it and it will take them to other pages as well.

[image]

3. PageBulkBuys (This is one of the pages that displays the product details etc)

[image]

Problem to be fixed.

- I just want to remove the double toolbar that's currently being displayed on the homepage and also the subpages.

Note that if I were to click on one of the menu links, this problem disappears and it only shows one tool bar.

[image]

However If I click on one of the links in the homepage, it shows a double tool bar which is really strange.

I've tried a few solutions online but no luck.

Here's my code:

App.CS

```
public App()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainHomePage());
   }
```

MainHomePage XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xxxxx.MainHomePage" xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:xxxxx">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MainHomePageMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="Black">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainHomePageDetail />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MainHomePage CS

```
public partial class MainHomePage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainHomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
        }
        
        [Obsolete]
        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MainHomePageMenuItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;
            if (item.Id == 10) // BulkBuys
                Navigation.PushAsync(new BulkBuys());
        }
    }
```

MainHomePageDetail XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xxxx.MainHomePageDetail" Title="xxxx" BackgroundColor="Black">
   <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>  
        <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingcarticon" IconImageSource="xxxxxx.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>  
   </ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>

            <Image Source="xxxxx.png" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="50"/>

            <Label x:Name="labelLoggedInUser" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18"></Label>

            <!-- Banner 1 -->
            <Frame x:Name="frame1" BackgroundColor="#2e2e2e">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image x:Name="Banner1Image" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="200">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="BtnBulkBargains"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Green" HasShadow="False" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="250" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="00">
                        <Label x:Name="Banner1Text" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label x:Name="Banner1Header" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                 </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <!-- Banner 2 -->
            <Frame x:Name="frame2" BackgroundColor="#2e2e2e">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image x:Name="Banner2Image" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="125"></Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
```

MainHomePageDetail CS

```
public MainHomePageDetail()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
private void ShoppingCartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewFBShoppingCart());
   }
```

BulkBuysPage XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="xxxx.PageBulkBuys"
             Title="Bulk Buys"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>  
        <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingcarticon" IconImageSource="xxxx.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>  
   </ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <Image Source="xxxx.png" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="50"/>

            <ListView x:Name="productsListView"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"                       
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" Padding="20" Margin="20">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding featured_src}"/>
                                        <Label x:Name="labelProductTitle" Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="00">
                                            <Label WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding price, StringFormat='${0}'}" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

BulkBuysPage CS

```
public PageBulkBuys()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
   }
private void ShoppingCartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewFBShoppingCart());
   }
```

**Any help would greatly be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used the `NavigationPage` in your `App.cs`,it will create a toolbar for you：

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainHomePage());
```

try to change it to :

```
MainPage = new MainHomePage();
```

or use  `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar` method in your `MainHomePage` to hide the toolbar :

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainHomePage());
    }

public MainHomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @LeoZhu-MSFT I tried that already, it does remove the double toolbars but then it opens another problem where the menu doesn't work anymore when I try to click on them and shows the error "PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage."

Comment: @Khoa I see,you call  `Navigation.PushAsync` in your `MainHomePage`  which means the new page you want to open is in the same stack with your `MainHomePage` ,you could try the another method which i update above to hide the navigationbar.

Comment: It works! Thanks @LeoZhu-MSFT!! :D I hope you get rich in 2021 and beyond.